# Copy one column to another column based ibn condition in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

```
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
    <th>NAME</th>
   <th> <input type="checkbox" name="" id="approvechk" value="1">  APPROVE</th>
   <th><input type="checkbox" name="" id="disapprovechk"> DISAPPROVE</th>

 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td approve>Jill</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td approve>Jack</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td disapprove>Doe</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

when I click the approve or disapprove checkbox the names which has corresponding approve or disapprove attribute should get filled on the respective APPROVE and DISAPPROVE columns. How can I do this in a easy using Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of what you ask for.

You can use :

`$("#approvechk").prop("checked");`

to see if your checkbox is checked or not. The return value is a boolean.

Then, I use `nth-child` selector to choose the right column :

```
$("table tr:nth-child("+tableIndex+") td:nth-child(2)").html($(value).text());
```

Keep in mind that `nth-child` index starts at one. So the table index starts at 2.

I am sure there is a cleaner way. This code works though, try it :

https://jsfiddle.net/mantisse_fr/g8rehfmh/